# Extracting data out from javascript code from an webpage

Tags: json, python-3.x, sqlite, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the data which will have the structure of the code i have  pasted below and from this data i would like to extract the X and y for each 10v, 20V... and keep them separated. I am ultimately planning to generate a plot of each of them after the parsing for the list of the data i will have.

The Soup:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-72511212-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<title>Metabolite Chart</title>
<!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
<script src="lib/js/jquery-1.6.x/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/js/misc/highcharts.src.delta.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/highcharts.js"></script>-->
<script src="lib/js/misc/excanvas.compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
-->
<!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
<script type="text/javascript">

        //alert("molI: " + "203");
        //alert("molN: " + "Chenodeoxycholic acid glycine conjugate");
        $(document).ready(function() {

            //alert("molN: " + "Chenodeoxycholic acid glycine conjugate");
            //  function resetchart() {
            //  fireEvent(chart, 'selection', { resetSelection: true }, zoom);
            //  }
            var count = 0;
            //alert("molI: " + "203");
            //var mid = 203;                // Pass MID here!
            var mid = "203";                // Pass 
            var mole = "Chenodeoxycholic acid glycine conjugate";           // Pass molecule name here!


            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                    zoomType: 'xy',
                    margin: [50, 50, 200, 80]
                },
                title: {
                    text: '' + mole
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: "MID: 203&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color='blue'><b>Insilico predicted spectra<\/b><\/font>"                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    //  max: 200,
                    title: {
                        enabled: true,
                        text: 'Mass (m/z)'
                    },
                    maxZoom: 0.1,
                    tickPixelInterval: 100
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Intensity (%)'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true,
                    showFragments: true,
                    showNeutrals: false,
                    showPeaks: false,
                    exclusiveSelect: true,    // Turns on exclusive radio style buttons
                    dblClick: false,
                    startNumber: 0, // The default legend item when page loads
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    style: {
                        left: '50px',
                        top: '300px',
                        bottom: 'auto'
                    }
                },
                // Tooltip HTML
                tooltip: {
                    second: true,
                    neutral: false,
                    borderRadius: 0, 
                    formatter: function() {
                        var namestr;
                        if (this.series.name.match(/\+/g) && !this.series.name.match("Cl"))
                            namestr = "Mode: <b><font size=\"4\">(+)</font></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Collision Energy: ";
                        else if (this.series.name.match('-'))
                            namestr = "Mode: <b><font size=\"4\">(-)</font></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Collision Energy: ";
                        if (!(this.series.name.match("10 V")||this.series.name.match("20 V")||this.series.name.match("40 V")))
                            namestr += "<b><font size=\"3\">0 V</font></b>";
                        else if (this.series.name.match("10 V"))
                            namestr += "<b><font size=\"3\">10 V</font></b>";
                        else if (this.series.name.match("20 V"))
                            namestr += "<b><font size=\"3\">20 V</font></b>";
                        else if (this.series.name.match("40 V"))
                            namestr += "<b><font size=\"3\">40 V</font></b>";
                       return '<center><br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '+ namestr +'<br/>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; m/z: <b><font size="3">' + this.x.toFixed(4) + '</font></b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Intensity: <b><font size="3">' + parseInt(Math.abs(this.y)) + ' % &nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></center><br/>';
                    },
                    formatter2: function() {
                        var namestr;
                        if (this.series.name.match(/\+/g))
                            namestr = "Mode: (+), &nbsp;&nbsp; Collision Energy: ";
                        else if (this.series.name.match('-'))
                            namestr = "Mode: (-), &nbsp;&nbsp; Collision Energy: ";

                        if (!(this.series.name.match("10 V")||this.series.name.match("20 V")||this.series.name.match("40 V")))
                            namestr += "0 V, &nbsp;&nbsp; Adduct: ";
                        else if (this.series.name.match("10 V"))
                            namestr += "10 V, &nbsp;&nbsp; Adduct: ";
                        else if(this.series.name.match("20 V"))
                            namestr += "20 V, &nbsp;&nbsp; Adduct: ";
                        else if (this.series.name.match("40 V"))
                            namestr += "40 V, &nbsp;&nbsp; Adduct: ";

                                                return false;
                    }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            pointPadding: 0.53,
                            // pointPadding: 0.99,
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            shadow: false
                            // borderColor: '#000000'
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{name: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (+) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 10 V &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; [M+H]+ &nbsp;&nbsp;',data:[{x:450.321,y:84,fragment: false},{x:434.29,y:0,fragment: false},{x:432.311,y:8,fragment: false},{x:432.311,y:100,fragment: false},{x:416.28,y:0,fragment: false},{x:414.3,y:24,fragment: false},{x:406.332,y:0,fragment: false},{x:404.316,y:16,fragment: false},{x:390.3,y:0,fragment: false},{x:390.264,y:0,fragment: false},{x:388.321,y:0,fragment: false},{x:386.305,y:8,fragment: false},{x:375.289,y:24,fragment: false},{x:372.29,y:0,fragment: false},{x:357.279,y:12,fragment: false},{x:347.294,y:4,fragment: false},{x:331.3,y:0,fragment: false},{x:329.284,y:4,fragment: false},{x:319.263,y:0,fragment: false},{x:301.253,y:0,fragment: false},{x:291.232,y:0,fragment: false},{x:273.221,y:0,fragment: false},{x:240.159,y:0,fragment: false},{x:158.081,y:0,fragment: false},{x:130.05,y:0,fragment: false},{x:76.0393,y:44,fragment: false},{x:74.0237,y:0,fragment: false},{x:59.0128,y:8,fragment: false},{x:58.0287,y:0,fragment: false},{x:30.0338,y:0,fragment: false},{x:28.0182,y:0,fragment: false} ]},{name: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (+) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 20 V &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; [M+H]+ &nbsp;&nbsp;',data:[{x:450.321,y:11.764705882353,fragment: false},{x:434.29,y:0,fragment: false},{x:432.311,y:35.294117647059,fragment: false},{x:432.311,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:416.28,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:414.3,y:58.823529411765,fragment: false},{x:404.316,y:11.764705882353,fragment: false},{x:388.321,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:386.305,y:35.294117647059,fragment: false},{x:375.289,y:29.411764705882,fragment: false},{x:372.29,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:357.279,y:35.294117647059,fragment: false},{x:347.294,y:17.647058823529,fragment: false},{x:333.279,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:331.3,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:329.284,y:17.647058823529,fragment: false},{x:327.268,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:319.263,y:0,fragment: false},{x:315.268,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:301.253,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:273.221,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:158.081,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:130.05,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:111.08,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:102.019,y:0,fragment: false},{x:76.0393,y:100,fragment: false},{x:74.0237,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:59.0128,y:23.529411764706,fragment: false},{x:58.0287,y:17.647058823529,fragment: false},{x:30.0338,y:11.764705882353,fragment: false},{x:28.0182,y:11.764705882353,fragment: false} ]},{name: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (+) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 40 V &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; [M+H]+ &nbsp;&nbsp;',data:[{x:416.28,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:414.3,y:100,fragment: false},{x:388.321,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:386.305,y:54.545454545455,fragment: false},{x:372.29,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:359.294,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:357.279,y:63.636363636364,fragment: false},{x:355.263,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:333.279,y:0,fragment: false},{x:331.3,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:331.263,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:329.284,y:36.363636363636,fragment: false},{x:327.268,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:317.284,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:315.268,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:303.268,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:301.253,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:275.237,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:273.221,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:261.221,y:0,fragment: false},{x:111.08,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:97.0648,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:76.0393,y:45.454545454545,fragment: false},{x:59.0128,y:63.636363636364,fragment: false},{x:58.0287,y:81.818181818182,fragment: false},{x:55.0542,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:44.9971,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:41.0022,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:32.0495,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:30.0338,y:36.363636363636,fragment: false},{x:28.0182,y:54.545454545455,fragment: false} ]}]
                }); 

            });
        </script>
</head>
<body style="border:0;overflow:visible">
<!-- 3. Add the container -->
<div id="container" style="width: 720px; height: 460px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
<!-- <table align = "center" style="border-width:0; cellpadding:5; table-layout:fixed; bordercolor:'#00FF00'"> -->
<table align="center" style="border-width:0; cellpadding:5; table-layout:fixed; bordercolor:'#00FF00'">
<tr>
<td style="border-style: solid; border-color:#FFF8C6"><img align="top" alt="attention" src="img/attn.png" title="how to use spectrum"/>  
                            <font color="red" face="helvetica,arial" size="2">
<b>Please mouse over the spectrum to view the detail information of each peak<br/>
                                        Use left mouse button to zoom in (click and drag) and zoom out (double-click)</b></font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

                    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1907670-5']);
                    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                    (function() {
                        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                    })();

                </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The data i am trying to extract out:

```
series: [{name: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (+) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 10 V &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; [M+H]+ &nbsp;&nbsp;',data:[{x:450.321,y:84,fragment: false},{x:434.29,y:0,fragment: false},{x:432.311,y:8,fragment: false},{x:432.311,y:100,fragment: false},{x:416.28,y:0,fragment: false},{x:414.3,y:24,fragment: false},{x:406.332,y:0,fragment: false},{x:404.316,y:16,fragment: false},{x:390.3,y:0,fragment: false},{x:390.264,y:0,fragment: false},{x:388.321,y:0,fragment: false},{x:386.305,y:8,fragment: false},{x:375.289,y:24,fragment: false},{x:372.29,y:0,fragment: false},{x:357.279,y:12,fragment: false},{x:347.294,y:4,fragment: false},{x:331.3,y:0,fragment: false},{x:329.284,y:4,fragment: false},{x:319.263,y:0,fragment: false},{x:301.253,y:0,fragment: false},{x:291.232,y:0,fragment: false},{x:273.221,y:0,fragment: false},{x:240.159,y:0,fragment: false},{x:158.081,y:0,fragment: false},{x:130.05,y:0,fragment: false},{x:76.0393,y:44,fragment: false},{x:74.0237,y:0,fragment: false},{x:59.0128,y:8,fragment: false},{x:58.0287,y:0,fragment: false},{x:30.0338,y:0,fragment: false},{x:28.0182,y:0,fragment: false} ]},{name: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (+) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 20 V &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; [M+H]+ &nbsp;&nbsp;',data:[{x:450.321,y:11.764705882353,fragment: false},{x:434.29,y:0,fragment: false},{x:432.311,y:35.294117647059,fragment: false},{x:432.311,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:416.28,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:414.3,y:58.823529411765,fragment: false},{x:404.316,y:11.764705882353,fragment: false},{x:388.321,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:386.305,y:35.294117647059,fragment: false},{x:375.289,y:29.411764705882,fragment: false},{x:372.29,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:357.279,y:35.294117647059,fragment: false},{x:347.294,y:17.647058823529,fragment: false},{x:333.279,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:331.3,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:329.284,y:17.647058823529,fragment: false},{x:327.268,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:319.263,y:0,fragment: false},{x:315.268,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:301.253,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:273.221,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:158.081,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:130.05,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:111.08,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:102.019,y:0,fragment: false},{x:76.0393,y:100,fragment: false},{x:74.0237,y:5.8823529411765,fragment: false},{x:59.0128,y:23.529411764706,fragment: false},{x:58.0287,y:17.647058823529,fragment: false},{x:30.0338,y:11.764705882353,fragment: false},{x:28.0182,y:11.764705882353,fragment: false} ]},{name: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (+) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 40 V &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; [M+H]+ &nbsp;&nbsp;',data:[{x:416.28,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:414.3,y:100,fragment: false},{x:388.321,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:386.305,y:54.545454545455,fragment: false},{x:372.29,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:359.294,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:357.279,y:63.636363636364,fragment: false},{x:355.263,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:333.279,y:0,fragment: false},{x:331.3,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:331.263,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:329.284,y:36.363636363636,fragment: false},{x:327.268,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:317.284,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:315.268,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:303.268,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:301.253,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:275.237,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:273.221,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:261.221,y:0,fragment: false},{x:111.08,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:97.0648,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:76.0393,y:45.454545454545,fragment: false},{x:59.0128,y:63.636363636364,fragment: false},{x:58.0287,y:81.818181818182,fragment: false},{x:55.0542,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:44.9971,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:41.0022,y:18.181818181818,fragment: false},{x:32.0495,y:9.0909090909091,fragment: false},{x:30.0338,y:36.363636363636,fragment: false},{x:28.0182,y:54.545454545455,fragment: false} ]}]
```

i am having trouble getting to that segment of the data and extracting it in a way that is useful. I did notice it has a JSON format structure but i cant gain access to it from the soup to make use of that.

If i am not clear on what i am trying to do please let me know.

Below is my python script:

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.request
import xlwt
import xlrd
import requests
import re
import json

CASNUMBERS =xlrd.open_workbook("./OUTPUTFILE.xls")
CASNUMBERS_sheet = CASNUMBERS.sheet_by_index(0)

# import sqlite3
# conn = sqlite3.connect('CurationParsedData.db')
# c = conn.cursor()
#
# ##Create Table
# c.execute('''CREATE TABLE CurationParsedData(Exp_website TEXT,InSilico_website TEXT)''')
#
#
# def add_website(exp,insil):
#     c.execute("INSERT INTO CurationParsedData VALUES("+ exp ","+ insil")")



# MID = "154"
# NAMEID = "glucose"
# CASID = "492-62-6"
# KEGGID = "C00267"


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

def ESILINK(number):
    ESIlink = "https://metlin.scripps.edu/showChart.php?molid=" + number + "&h=240&collE=&Imode=p&etype=experimental"
    return ESIlink


def insilico(number):
    insilicolink = "https://metlin.scripps.edu/showChart.php?molid=" + number + "&h=240&collE=&Imode=p&etype=insilico"
    return insilicolink

def metlinsearch(NAME= "",CAS = "", KEGG=""):
    metlin_search = "https://metlin.scripps.edu/advanced_search_result.php?molid=&mass_min=&mass_max=&name=" + NAME + "&formula=&cas=" + CAS + "&kegg=" + KEGG + "&smilefile=&msmspeaks_min=&AminoAcid=add&drug=add&toxinEPA=add&smilesExactMatchCheckBox=false&nameExactMatchCheckBox=false"
    return  metlin_search

def HMDBsearch(number):
    hmdb_search = "http://www.hmdb.ca/unearth/q?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=" + number + "&searcher=metabolites&button="
    return hmdb_search


for items in CASNUMBERS_sheet.col_values(2, 1):
    print(items)

    hmdbsearch_link = HMDBsearch(items)

    print(hmdbsearch_link)

    metlinsearch_link = metlinsearch(CAS = items)
    metlinesearch_soup = make_soup(metlinsearch_link)

    firstMID = metlinesearch_soup.find("th", {"scope": "row"})
    allMID = metlinesearch_soup.findAll("th", {"scope": "row"})
    ESI = "NO LINK"
    INSILICO = "NO LINK"
    if firstMID != None:
        firstMID = firstMID.text
        ESI = ESILINK(firstMID)
        INSILICO = insilico(firstMID)

    if allMID != None:
        MIDlist = []
        for items in allMID:
            MIDlist.append(items.text)
    esi = ESILINK(ESI)
    sil = insilico(INSILICO)
    print(ESI)
    print(INSILICO)
    # sil_soup = make_soup(sil)
    sil_link = requests.get(INSILICO)
    sil_soup = BeautifulSoup(sil_link.text, "lxml")
    # print(sil_soup)
    series = sil_soup.findAll('script', {"type": "text/javascript"})
    series = series[3]
    info = []
    for x in series:
        info.append(str(x))

    for text in info:
        head, body, tail = text.partition('series:')
        tail = tail.replace('&nbsp', '').replace(';', '').replace(' ', '')
        print(tail)
        json_string = tail
        parse_json= json.loads(json_string)
        print(parse_json['data'])
```

Comment: "i cant gain access to it from the soup to make use of that" - That's because `urllib` doesn't handle `requests`, you could use `selenium` for that. For the url given I can't find that piece of data while inspecting the page, can you explicitly give one url you are working?

Comment: The data i am looking for is visable in the soup .(ie. https://metlin.scripps.edu/showChart.php?molid=203&h=240&collE=&Imode=p&etype=insilico) i am able to filter out the other excess text by using   series = sil_soup.findAll('script', {"type": "text/javascript"}). But i can not get the data i want from the soup.

Comment: I was able to manipulate the data to a string then remove rest of the unwanted characters, now i am running into issues with extracting that relevant data  to a table to plot.

Comment: This was the code i added: sil_link = requests.get(INSILICO)
    sil_soup = BeautifulSoup(sil_link.text, "lxml")
    # print(sil_soup)
    series = sil_soup.findAll('script', {"type": "text/javascript"})
    series = series[3]
    info = []
    for x in series:
        info.append(str(x))

    for text in info:
        head, body, tail = text.partition('series:')
        tail = tail.replace('&nbsp', '').replace(';', '').replace(' ', '')
        print(tail)
        json_string = tail
        parse_json= json.loads(json_string)
        print(parse_json['data'])

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the output i wanted by a few steps, definitely not the best and optimal way but i first turned it in to a string -> partition to get to the part i needed -> removed characters that were not of interest from the string -> run it through a for loop to reorganize the data back into a list -> run through and partition for x and y values -> convert to float -> values can be used for graphing.

very round about way to get the task done but might help someone with similar issues when trying to parse JavaScript data.

below is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.request
import xlwt
import xlrd
import requests
import re
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


CASNUMBERS =xlrd.open_workbook("./OUTPUTFILE.xls")
CASNUMBERS_sheet = CASNUMBERS.sheet_by_index(0)

# import sqlite3
# conn = sqlite3.connect('CurationParsedData.db')
# c = conn.cursor()
#
# ##Create Table
# c.execute('''CREATE TABLE CurationParsedData(Exp_website TEXT,InSilico_website TEXT)''')
#
#
# def add_website(exp,insil):
#     c.execute("INSERT INTO CurationParsedData VALUES("+ exp ","+ insil")")

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

def ESILINK(number):
    ESIlink = "https://metlin.scripps.edu/showChart.php?molid=" + number + "&h=240&collE=&Imode=p&etype=experimental"
    return ESIlink


def insilico(number):
    insilicolink = "https://metlin.scripps.edu/showChart.php?molid=" + number + "&h=240&collE=&Imode=p&etype=insilico"
    return insilicolink

def metlinsearch(NAME= "",CAS = "", KEGG=""):
    metlin_search = "https://metlin.scripps.edu/advanced_search_result.php?molid=&mass_min=&mass_max=&name=" + NAME + "&formula=&cas=" + CAS + "&kegg=" + KEGG + "&smilefile=&msmspeaks_min=&AminoAcid=add&drug=add&toxinEPA=add&smilesExactMatchCheckBox=false&nameExactMatchCheckBox=false"
    return  metlin_search

def HMDBsearch(number):
    hmdb_search = "http://www.hmdb.ca/unearth/q?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=" + number + "&searcher=metabolites&button="
    return hmdb_search


for items in CASNUMBERS_sheet.col_values(2, 1):
    print(items)

    hmdbsearch_link = HMDBsearch(items)

    print(hmdbsearch_link)

    metlinsearch_link = metlinsearch(CAS = items)
    metlinesearch_soup = make_soup(metlinsearch_link)

    firstMID = metlinesearch_soup.find("th", {"scope": "row"})
    allMID = metlinesearch_soup.findAll("th", {"scope": "row"})
    ESI = "NO LINK"
    INSILICO = "NO LINK"
    if firstMID != None:
        firstMID = firstMID.text
        ESI = ESILINK(firstMID)
        INSILICO = insilico(firstMID)

    if allMID != None:
        MIDlist = []
        for items in allMID:
            MIDlist.append(items.text)
    esi = ESILINK(ESI)
    sil = insilico(INSILICO)
    print(ESI)
    print(INSILICO)
    if ESI != "NO LINK":
        sil_link = requests.get(ESI)
        sil_soup = BeautifulSoup(sil_link.text, "lxml")
        # print(sil_soup)
        series = sil_soup.findAll('script', {"type": "text/javascript"})
        series = series[3]
        info = []
        for x in series:
            info.append(str(x))
        for text in info:
            head, body, tail = text.partition('series:')
            tail = tail.replace('&nbsp', '').replace(';', '').replace(' ', '').replace('fragment:false', '').replace('fragment:true', '').replace('\n', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('name:', '').replace('data:', '')
            # print(tail)
        identifyers = ['{', '}']
        datalist = []
        temp = ''
        for data in tail:
            if data != identifyers:
                temp = temp + data
                # print(temp)
                # print('active1')
            if data in identifyers:
                datalist.append(temp)
                temp = ''
                # print("active2")
        # print(datalist)
        finallist = []
        for items in datalist:
            items = items.replace("}", '').replace('{', '').replace(',', '').replace(')', '').replace('(','')
            if items != '':
                finallist.append(items)
        print(finallist)
        for items in finallist:
            if items[0] == "x":
                head,body,tail = items.partition("x:")
                head,body,tail = tail.partition("y:")
                xvalue = round(float(head), 3)
                yvalue = round(float(tail), 3)
                print("x:",xvalue, "y:", yvalue)
            else:
                # items[1] == "-" or "+":
                print("energy", items)
```